# How to upload custom font and use it in angular 6 dynamically

Tags: angular, dynamic, fonts

I am working in angular 6 project  and I need to to give functionality of user uploaded font and use it.

I have also try below code :

```
var junction_font = new FontFace('example_font_family', 'url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/gloriahallelujah/v9/LYjYdHv3kUk9BMV96EIswT9DIbW-MIS11zM.woff2)');
        junction_font.load().then(function (loaded_face) {
          document.fonts.add(loaded_face);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log('error : ', error);
        });

HTML:
<p style="example_font_family">Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

But this code show me an error at two place

1) cannot find name FontFace  (FontFace object not supprted in angular)

2) Property 'fonts' does not exist on type 'Document'.  (document.font object not supprted in angular)

Here is fiddle working in js but not working in typescript: http://jsfiddle.net/Mark_1998/xvpk0rnm/3/

Is there any alternative for load font dynamically in angular.
please help me.

Comment: May I know if all the font are from google font or web font with url ?

Comment: This is only example. actually all font are coming from my server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## 1. Existing CSS link

Assume your web font is an external css like [Google Font](https://fonts.google.com), [Adobe Typekit](https://fonts.adobe.com/typekit) or your own css url.

In `app.component.ts`,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  // Change whatever your like
  public link = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans+TC"


  constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {
    this.sanitizer = sanitizer;
  }

  getFontCSS() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.link);
  }
}
```

In `app.component.html`

```
<link [href]="getFontCSS()" rel="stylesheet">
<p [ngStyle]="{'font-family': 'Noto Sans TC'}">Lorem ipsum</p>
<p [ngStyle]="{'font-family': 'Arial'}">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Also, you may need to use `ViewEncapsulation.None` if you want the style apply to sub-components.

## 2. Non-exist CSS

Say you allow user to upload the font to `firebase storage` and trigger a `cloud functions`. Firebase allow you to write a new CSS to `/tmp` and upload to `firebase storage` and return a URL. Really depends which server and language you use.

## 3. Using FontFace (Not Recommended)

In `app.component.ts`,

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare let FontFace: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.loadFont()  
  }

  loadFont() {
    let customFont = new FontFace('barCode', 'url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/felipa/v6/FwZa7-owz1Eu4F_AT96F.woff2)');
    customFont.load().then((res) => {
      document['fonts'].add(res);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }
}
```

In `app.component.html`,

```
<p [ngStyle]="{'font-family': 'barCode'}">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

This is not recommended yet as FontFace is an experimental technology and `Working Draft`. There is cross-browser support issue.

Comment: Is there any way to use font without css FontFace ? (pure typescript)

Comment: Above code is typescript already ... guess it is your IDE validation. You could add the type your want or tell me what kind of error you have

Comment: My user upload flow is like this : 
When user upload font, server return me it's url
when user select that font from dropdown, I just want to load that font in angular and set font family to dom element. (without declare css fontFace)

Comment: but problem is that if i implement this code in js file then it is working. but when same font loading code put in agnualr then it show me an error in my IDE below `new FontFace` and `document.fonts` line

Comment: I already display error text in question placed at below of code.

Comment: You need a CSS to indicate the font family name so that you could use it as CSS. Or you need a server to read the font family of your woff. What server you use?

Comment: I am using amazon server.

Comment: Font family is set in font file already. You cannot read a arial.woff and name the font family to other font name.

Comment: If you are using `aws`, you could upload to `S3` and trigger a `lambda` function to write a CSS and upload to `S3` again

Comment: I have created one fiddle enable to load font from google without css use. I just want to convert this fiddle in typescript.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mark_1998/xvpk0rnm/3/

Comment: let's go through chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188376/discussion-between-mayur-kukadiya-and-hugomac).

Comment: It is not suggested to use `FontFace` as it is an experimental technology `Working Draft` only [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace). There is cross browser issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. I will try to find some another way for upload fonts.

Comment: @mayurkukadiya, I have updated the answer. Please check Point 3. Please be reminded that not every browser could work. esp `loaded()`