# How to change the font-family of paragraph on button click in angular 8

Tags: javascript, css, angular, styles, ionic4

I am trying to make a web app where the user can set any font-style provided by the app for his writing.

I am using 20-30 font-style. I am trying to set them dynamically on the button click using `[ngStyle]`

and passing styles like `{'font-family': 'Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif'}` But none of them work. Everything is working like `color, size` but not `font-family`.

Can you tell me the correct procedure or What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54683087/how-to-upload-custom-font-and-use-it-in-angular-6-dynamically also you can check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to set font dynamically using ngStyle as you described and it worked for me. [Look at this code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5hycqp)

```
font = 'Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif';

setFont() {
    this.font = this.font ==='Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif' ? 'Ariel' : 'Roboto, Helvetica, sans-serif'
}
```

```
<button  type="button"  (click)="setFont()">ADD</button>
<div [ngStyle]="{'font-family': font}">{{ font }}</div>
```

Comment: I don't know, but it's working now :(